# .NET Java SOAP service change to WCF soap service

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I currently have soap web services in java. Due to some architectural changes we need to move the services to WCF.

If the signatures are the same, can the string URI be changed and the .NET proxy will continue to work without any changes to the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the contract (WSDL) remains absolutely the same then you only need to change address to the new server hosting the service - that is the theory. Now you need to build the WCF service which will really have the same contract. That can be hard task. I would start with generating interfaces from existing WSDL describing Java service (use [svcutil](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx) for that).

Comment: All the SOAP definitions are based on XSDS. The .NET code used xsd.exe to generated the base classes. So as long as the Data Contracts for the WCF services use the same XSDs as a base I should be OK. Thanks for the suggestion for using svcutil.